# Kubernetes: How do I find which jobs a cronjob has generated

Tags: kubernetes

Say that I have a job history limit > 1, is there a way to use kubectl to find which jobs that have been spawned by a CronJob?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use label.

```
$kubectl get jobs -n namespace -l created-by=cronjob
```

**created-by=cronjob** which define at your cronjob.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        created-by: cronjob
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would use the --field-selector label to get all jobs belonging to a particular CronJob, but field selector does not support all the fields. The best way I could find is using jsonPath:

Substitute CronJobName to the name of your cronjob to get all jobs that belong to that CronJob

```
kubectl get jobs $(kubectl get jobs -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.ownerReferences[*].name=="CronJobName")].metadata.name}')
```

Comment: Nice with a oneliner, however I was looking for something that didn't require me to make two requests. I realize now that I didn't specify that.